# CCMenuItemLabel doesn't work when isTouchEnabled is true?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am working on my Cocos2d-x cpp project. I have successfully add touch event to move the background in Layer. Now I want to add CCMenuItemLabel to the Layer, but I find that CCMenuItemLabel doesn't work when I Touch it. How can I solve it?

I have add these functions in my Layer:

```
virtual void ccTouchesBegan (CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchesMoved (CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchesEnded (CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

In MyLayer::init() function:

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);

CCLabelTTF* test = CCLabelTTF::create("tesetdd","Arial",40);
CCMenuItemLabel* menuLabel = CCMenuItemLabel::create(test,this,menu_selector(GameWall::menuCall));
menuLabel->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2));
this->addChild(menuLabel,1);
```

Update:I have put CCMenuItemLabel into the CCMenu. But it still doesn't work.

```
CCLabelTTF* test = CCLabelTTF::create("tesetdd","Arial",40);
CCMenuItemLabel* menuLabel = CCMenuItemLabel::create(test,this,menu_selector(GameWall::menuCall));
menuLabel->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2));
CCMenu* menu = CCMenu::create(menuLabel,NULL);
menu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
this->addChild(menu,1);
```

Comment: 1. Is it working without touchEnable? 2.check syntax of your callback.

Comment: @Rama CCMenuItem can work without touchEnable, but if you set touchEnable true, CCMenu cannot work. But anyway thanks, I have solve the problem give the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks for @Kreiri.

I have change my Touch Event function to

```
virtual bool ccTouchBegan (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchMoved (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
virtual void ccTouchEnded (CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent);
```

and I add two more functions

```
virtual void onEnter();
virtual void registerWithTouchDispatcher();
```

and I move initial code to onEnter

```
CCLabelTTF* test = CCLabelTTF::create("tesetdd","Arial",40);
CCMenuItemLabel* menuLabel =          CCMenuItemLabel::create(test,this,menu_selector(GameWall::menuCall));
menuLabel->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2));
CCMenu* menu = CCMenu::create(menuLabel,NULL);
menu->setPosition(CCPointZero);
this->addChild(menu,1);
```

add three more code to onEnter():

```
this->setTouchEnabled(true);
registerWithTouchDispatcher();
menu->registerWithTouchDispatcher();
```

While registerWithTouchDispatcher() :

```
void GameWall::registerWithTouchDispatcher(){
    //registe the single point touch,and take over all touch event
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this,kCCMenuHandlerPriority,true);
}
```

Finally, don't forget to romoveDelegate() in onExit():

```
void GameWall::onExit(){
    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->removeDelegate(this);
}
```

Let me explain, check the document registerWithTouchDispatcher() says `If isTouchEnabled, this method is called onEnter.` and `Override it to change the way CCLayer receives touch events.` And same with CCMenu.

Answer (score 1):

Don't add CCMenuItems directly to layer. Add them to a CCMenu and add that CCMenu to your layer.